# How to add m4v files to iPod classic using Banshee

Tags: video, banshee, sync, ipod

I am running Gnome Shell 3.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 and Banshee 2.2.

I sync Banshee with my iPod Classic 80 gb. I have enabled syncing music - sync entire library option and video syncing is set to manual.

When I drag m4v files from my Banshee library to my iPod, it gives an error 'The m4v format is not supported by this device, and no converter was found to convert it'.

Of course my iPod can play m4v files - I had synced it in iTunes earlier without any difficulty.

What is missing? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak for your situation, but for me this is related only to LOSSLESS m4a files. Nevertheless, I have the same problem, both with banshee and with gtkpod. This is a confirmed bug in 11.10. A poor answer, but for now I suggest subscribing to the bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtkpod/+bug/883962

It appears to be the result of missing libmp4v2, which was dropped from 11.10. There are some workarounds suggested at the bug site, but a workaround isn't an 'answer' in the strict sense.